# Hover.css Library Animations not working in Firefox or Edge, but works in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

For some odd reason, an answer I cannot find, is why this library does not working in Firefox or Edge?!?! I add an underline animation to a navbar tab and nothing happens except for the text that is suppose to turn red.

Below is the code for my index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang = "en">

<head>

<title>Klassic</title>    

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">  

<meta charset="UTF-8">    

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type ="text/css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Armata" rel="stylesheet">

<link href = "animate.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href = "hover.css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

<link href = "hover.css/hover-min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">    

</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default container navbar-centered" role="navigation">

<div class="navbar-header">

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>


    </button>    

</div>

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li class = "hvr-underline-from-center navbar-button-font"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

        <li class = "navbar-button-font hvr-underline-from-center"><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>

        <li class = "navbar-button-font hvr-underline-from-center"><a href="#">Teams</a></li>

        <li class = "navbar-button-font hvr-underline-from-center"><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>

        <li class = "navbar-button-font hvr-underline-from-center"><a href="#">Results</a></li>

        <li class = "navbar-button-font hvr-underline-from-center"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>

    <script type = "text/javascript">

              $(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {

              if( $(e.target).is('a') && $(e.target).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle' ) {

              $(this).collapse('hide');
           }
        });


       </script>

       <script type = "text/javascript">

                $('ul.nav [data-toggle=dropdown').on({

                mouseenter: function(event) {

                if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {

                $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');

                }
            }
        });

        </script>

      <script type = "text/javascript">

                $('ul.nav .dropdown, .dropdown-submenu').on({

                mouseleave: function(event) {

                if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {

                $(this).toggleClass('open');

                }
            }
        });

     </script>

     <script type = "text/javascript">

                $(document).click(function (event) {

                var clickover = $(event.target);

                var $navbar = $(".navbar-collapse");               

                var _opened = $navbar.hasClass("in");

                if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbartoggle"))   {      

                $navbar.collapse('hide');
            }
        });

       </script>



        </nav>

        </body>


        </html>
```

Below is my code for my style.css

```
.navbar {

margin-top: 30px;
border-color: red;

}

.navbar-toggle {


position: relative;
float: left;
padding: 20px 20px;
margin-top: 8px;
margin-right: -20px;
margin-left: 21px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: none;
border-color: black;
border-radius: 4px;
text-align: center;
z-index: 3;


}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-centered .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;

}
.navbar-centered .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-centered .nav > li {
    display: inline;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    padding-top: 19px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px; 

}
.navbar-centered .nav > li > a {
    display: inline-block;
}
}

 /* Makes Navbar activate collapse earlier */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    display: block !important;
}
.navbar-header .collapse, .navbar-toggle {
    display:inline; !important;
}
.navbar-header {
    float:none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar {

background: transparent;

border-color: transparent

} 

.collapse {

background-color: white; !important;


}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {

border-color: white;
```

}

```
.navbar-toggle {

    margin-top: -19px 


}    

}

.navbar-button-font {


font-family: 'Armata', sans-serif;


}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {

color: red;
}

body {



}

.active {


 background-color: transparent;


 }

.hvr-underline-from-center {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 transform: translateZ(0);
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 }
.hvr-underline-from-center:before {
  content: "";
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 left: 50%;
 right: 50%;
 bottom: 0;
 background: red;
 height: 4px;
 -webkit-transition-property: left, right;
 transition-property: left, right;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
 }
 .hvr-underline-from-center:hover:before,     .hvr-underline-from-    

  center:focus:before,       .hvr-underline-from-center:active:before {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.hvr-underline-from-center` in the CSS, explicitly say `li..hvr-underline-from-center`.

Full Example:

```
 li.hvr-underline-from-center {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 transform: translateZ(0);
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 }
 li.hvr-underline-from-center:before      {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 left: 50%;
 right: 50%;
 bottom: 0;
 background: red;
 height: 4px;
 -webkit-transition-property: left, right;
 transition-property: left, right;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function; ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
 }
 li.hvr-underline-from-center:hover:before, li.hvr-underline-from-center:focus:before,  li.hvr-underline-from-center:active:before {
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
  }
```

For some reason, Firefox requires elements to be called out in CSS explicitly. This should work with edge and Firefox now.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your css source file path is right or not. if any every things is good please send me zip i will fix

Comment: How can I get a zip to you?

Comment: No I figured it out!

Comment: anupamurl@gmail.com is my mail id you can send on it

Comment: I found it out. I will post an answer